# How to change the indentation of compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-4.2

The indentation change from 4 to 8, how to convert it back to 4?

```
@Composable
fun <T> ListContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier  // The indentation I'd like to.
)

@Composable
fun <T> ListContent(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier  // But the indentation actually I get.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting code style of kotlin, everything work fine. (Preferences -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Continuation indent -> 4)